# how to generate multiple pages so that all fetched queries get in n number of pages?

Tags: php, mysql

fetching the queries using PDO, how to output all results such that output gets distributed in N number of pages & after X number of results on each page....only require with the help of next button not pagination (numbering). i want to break the below array `echo $r['rollno'];` in pages ?

```
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);

$sql="SELECT rollno FROM student";
$q=$conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo $r['rollno'];
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: okk...i will....how to achieve this using old or new code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysql LIMIT in your query:

```
$x = 10; // results on each page
$n = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 0; // pagenumber

$sql = "SELECT rollno FROM student LIMIT ".($x * $n).", $x";
```

and link to next page like this:

```
echo('<a href="?page='.($n+1).'">Next</a>');
```

Comment: ok...but how to print them in different pages one after other ?

Comment: edited my answer with a example on how you can make a next link

Comment: how to pass array  echo $r['rollno']; ?

Comment: maybe it will be easier if you use mysql LIMIT. see new edit